# Formula for $1/f(x)$ where $f$ is a polynomial

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, roots, partial-fractions

> Let $f$ be a polynomial having $n$ distinct real roots:
>   $$f(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\dots(x-x_n)$$
>   Prove that $$\frac{1}{f(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{f'(x_k)(x-x_k)}, \: \forall x \in \mathbb{R} - \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n \} $$

I don't know much about partial fractions, but this looks very much like them. I tried to use induction for this, but I couldn't really make the jump from $n-1$ to $n$ and I honestly wouldn't have been satisfied even if I had solved it that way, because I would really like to see where this formula comes from. I'm sorry if this is actually very easy, I simply don't know how to approach it

Comment: HINT: first try to find an expresson for the derivative of $f$ in terms of its zeroes

Comment: How familiar are you with complex analysis?

Comment: I don't know anything about it yet.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: complex analysis is not required at all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It might be unnecessary, but you can indeed use the fact that you are eliminating the poles of a haolomorphic function on $\Bbb C\setminus\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ which goes to zero as $z\to\infty$. Which also accounts for the need of all the roots to be there and to be distinct.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: I fail to see why this would help. The question is solved with algebra.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Fair enough. Not that I have intention of writing an answer like that (since the OP does not need it), so perhaps I am not aware of something I might be missing.

Comment: This formula is confusing to me. Doesn't the let left hand side asymptotically behave like $\frac1{O(x^n)}$ while the right hand side behaves like $\frac1{O(x)}$? I fail to see how these could agree for large values of $x$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried decomposing $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ into partial fractions. By that i mean writing $\frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{A_1}{x-x_1}+...+\frac{A_n}{x-x_n}$ and solving for each $A_i$? Then i think the first fraction would look something like $\frac{1}{(x-x_1)(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)...(x_1-x_n)}$. Then calculating $f'(x_1)$ should get you the result you want.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but how to I prove that $A_1$ equals that, for example?

Comment: Multiplying the equation by $(x-x_1)$ and then realizing that substituting $x_1$ into the equation would "kill of" the other fractions leaving $A_1=\frac{1}{(x_1-x_2)...(x_1-x_n)} $

Comment: Oh, silly me! You are right, thank you very much!

Comment: Regarding the calculation of $f'(x_1)$, i guess you could be a bit fancy and see that $\frac{1}{(x-x_1)(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)...(x_1-x_n)}=\lim_{a \rightarrow {x_1}} \frac{1}{(x-x_1)(a-x_2)(a-x_3)...(a-x_n)}$ and by expandig the fraction by $(a-x_1)$ you get $lim_{a \rightarrow {x_1}} \frac{(a-x_1)}{(x-x_1)(a-x_1)(a-x_2)(a-x_3)...(a-x_n)}$. And this is $\frac{1}{(x-x_1)f'(x_1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s(x)$ be the summation and notice that

$$s(x)f(x)$$ is the Lagrangian interpolation polynomial* on the points $\left(x_k,y_k\right)$ where $$y_k:=\frac{\prod\limits_{\substack{i\ne k}}(x_k-x_i)}{f'(x_k)}.$$

But we precisely have

$$f'(x_k)=\prod\limits_{\substack{i\ne k}}(x_k-x_i)$$

so that $$s(x)f(x)$$ is identically $1$.

---

*Identify with

$$\sum_{k} y_k\frac{\prod\limits_{\substack{i\ne k}}(x-x_i)}{\prod\limits_{\substack{i\ne k}}(x_k-x_i)}.$$

For conciseness the ranges $1, n$ have been left implicit.

Answer (score -1):

$1/(x-x1)(x-x2)..(x-xk)..=A/(x-x1)+B/(x-x2) ...K/(x-xk)..$

So When you multiply both sides by denominator you get,
$1=A(x-x2)..(x-xk..(x-xn)+B(x-x1)(x-x3)..(x-xk)..(x-xn) + K(x-x1)..(x-(k-1))(x-(k+1)..(x-xn)$

To find Constant K substitute $x=xk$

After cancelling all terms you end up with,
$K=1/(xk-x1)..(xk-(k-1))(xk-(k+1)..(xk-xn)$

We can express  $f(x)$ as follows,

$f(x)=(x-xk)*[(x-x1)(x-x2)..(x-(k-1))(x-(k+1)..(x-xn)]$

say

$g(x)=[(x-x1)(x-x2)..(x-(k-1))(x-(k+1)..(x-xn)]$

(also note that $K=1/g(xk)$)

Now $f(x)=(x-xk)*g(x)$

$f'(x)=(x-xk)g'(x)+g(x)*1$

when $x=xk$ is substituted, 
$f'(xk)=g(xk)$

So K th term is $1/(f'(xk)*(x-xk)$